# How to read CSV file values in Jenkins pipeline using groovy

Tags: csv, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to read a CSV file values. inside the CSV url and it's credentials. I need to read the first url and store in  variable for Jenkins pipeline

Answer (score 0):

def records= readCSV file : 'location of file'

you might need to install utility plugin for this